# Help finding central limit theorem approximations - Normal Distribution Equation

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, monte-carlo, central-limit-theorem

I was given f(x)=|x| as a probability distribution. I've summed the results of a Monte Carlo with N terms and plotted a thousand of these sums in a normalized histogram. Now I need to compare this with a normal distribution obtained via the central limit theorem. I've determined the mean will always be 0, and was told the variance for f(x) is 1/2. I am not sure how my normal distributions will depend on N however.

Comment: I thought maybe it was $(0.5\pi M)^{\0.5}e^{-(\frac{x}{M})^2$

Comment: What is the range of values for x that you are using? You need to specify this to know the mean and variance. The range cannot be unbounded.